# Prevent browser caching for .htaccess file itself

Tags: .htaccess, browser-cache

It took me a while to understand why my 301 redirects didn't work as expected.
The reason was that my .htaccess file was cached by my browser. To avoid that visitors to my website face similar issues, is there a way to prevent browsers from caching .htaccess?

Comment: why do you serve server-configuration to the client/browser ? this is not a cacheing problem but a sane server-setup / security problem

Comment: _“The reason was that my .htaccess file was cached by my browser.”_ - that makes little sense. This file is read by the server, to influence how _that_ behaves - the client browser normally doesn’t even get to see it. (I guess it _could_ be that you explicitly made it available for the client to request, so that you can quickly check if the content is what you think it should be, via the browser? But that would still not mean, that the browser cache had anything to do with the server configuration.)

Comment: Did you perhaps _actually_ mean, that an older, faulty _redirect_ got cached by your browser? That would make more sense. During development you should always use 302 as status code for such redirects, those do not get cached - only switch to 301 later, when you are sure everything works. If site visitors of yours already have faulty redirect cached on their end now - then you will simply have to wait, until that cache expires now. You can not modify a cache retro-actively.

Comment: What I wrote is incorrect, sorry about that: it's not the .htaccess file itself that is cached by browsers, but the 301 redirects it contains. So, if you make a mistake in a 301 and then test it, you'll be served the same wrong redirect until you empty your browser's cache. As you can't empty your visitors' browser cache, you'd better be careful when you redirect a page using a 301. I guess using a temporary redirect (302 or 307) for testing purposes, then change it to 301, would be wiser...

Comment: Thanks, CBroe. I just read your answer. After I had posted the above...